# Dates on a-axis in Google Charts line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Here's a newbie question, but how do I use dates for the x-axis in a [Google Charts line chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)?

When I use new Date( ... ) I get the error message "Uncaught Error: Date and datetime column types are not supported"

```
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Datum','Person1','Person2','Person3'],
[new Date(2012, 12, 19, 0, 0, 0),'5072.0537223002','5072.0537223002','5074.2809630567'],
[new Date(2012, 12, 20, 0, 0, 0),'5072.0537223002','5072.0537223002','5074.2809630567'],
]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

(Using strings evenly spaces across the x-axis would be acceptable, but when I try with strings "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about to convert the date to a string and just use `Date` without `new` like below :

```
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Datum','Person1','Person2','Person3'],
[Date(2012, 12, 19, 0, 0, 0).toString(),'5072.0537223002','5072.0537223002','5074.2809630567'],
[Date(2012, 12, 20, 0, 0, 0).toString(),'5072.0537223002','5072.0537223002','5074.2809630567'],
]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

**Edit:**
You can follow their example in this link :

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

**Edit 2:**

This is what I was able to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/ANC9H/2/

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["LineChart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'persone1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'persone2');
        data.addColumn('number', 'persone3');
        data.addRows([
                       [new Date(2008, 1 ,1),0.7,0.8,0.6],
                       [new Date(2008, 1 ,7),0.5,0.55,0.9] ]);
    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This gives me "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

Comment: @Calle Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to working just fine. I will try that later, and will most certainly tell you it worked excellently and mark this correct.

Comment: I got it working great now. Thank you a lot for your research and help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using arrayToDataTable(). If you use DataTable() the error message will go away. See this post : [Column Chart with date axis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916239/column-chart-with-date-axis-not-working/8923952#8923952)